# Import multiple zip files data through Azure DevOps pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, data-migration

[[](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ylprr.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lt4IW.png)

Does anyone know how i can import multiple data zip files to target environment using pipeline? This is my first time using pipeline, need guidance. I am currently can only import one Master Data to target environment. Need to update multiple times if i need to upload multiple zip files.

Comment: can you please share your method or  yaml code to show how you "import one Master Data".

Comment: Current information is very limited and we cannot understand your real requirements. You need to share more details about the current Pipeline settings ,requirements and what attempts have you made.

Comment: I have attached the picture (link). There is no YAML for this, i'm using the tools provided in ado

Comment: @user23301214 Do you mean that you need to upload multiple zip files in a single task?

Comment: Yes correct, i can only set to import one zip files. My requirements is to upload multiple Master Data zip files to target environment. Is this need to be done using YAML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your screenshot, you are using the Import Config Migration Data task from the extension: [Power DevOps Tools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=WaelHamze.xrm-ci-framework-build-tasks&ssr=false#overview)

When we use the task in Classic Release Pipeline, it only supports select one zip file at a task.  We are not able to select multiple files in a task

To upload multiple Master Data zip files to target environment in release Pipeline, you can add multiple tasks and a specific zip file in each task.

For example:

[image]

In this case, we can upload multiple Master Data zip files to target environment in one release Pipeline Run.

Or we can use YAML Pipeline to define multiple files for the task.

For example:

```
- task: MSCRMImportCMData@12
  displayName: 'Import Configuration Migration Data'
  inputs:
    crmConnectionString: xxxxx
    dataFile: |
       xxx/xxx/xxx/a.zip
       xxx/xxx/xxx/b.zip
```